# Edit a .docx file's text using python-docx do not save images

Tags: python, image, python-docx

I'm trying to edit the text of a .docx file using the docx library, but the images are obviously not preserved when saved in the new file.

The code is as follows:

```py
from docx import Document

doc = Document("./doc_files/test.docx")

for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:

    if not paragraph.runs:
        continue
    
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        run.text = "plop"

doc.save("./doc_files/test_ploped.docx")
```

My docx test file contains an image and a word. The size of this file is 4682KB.
When I run my program, the new file is 4678KB.
My first assumption was that the image was simply not copied into the new file.
The image is 190KB so the difference in weight should be higher if the image was removed from the new file.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the image was "inline" in the run you replaced the text of.

An inline image is stored in a run. Assigning to `Run.text` replaces everything in the run with the text you assign to it, which would include the image.

`python-docx` does not currently detect this and remove the image. This means that while there is no longer a reference to the image in the document part, there is still a relationship to it in the `document.xml.rels` part and the image part (something like `word/media/image1.png`) is still part of the package. This explains the file size staying about the same.

If you open the saved file in Word and re-save it, the orphaned image part may be removed.

There is currently no `Run.remove_picture()` method or anything like that to allow you to fully remove the picture. The common use cases for `python-docx` are to *add* things to documents (document creation) and read documents (text-extraction commonly) rather than take things away or move them around (document editing), although some editing is possible.